# Simplify access to nested java objects

Tags: java, lambda

I have to work with data structures that I can't influence and that give me objects nested into other objects. Sometimes I have to extract values from deep inside the data structure and at any level the objects may or may not exist, so I have to check for null pointers at any level e.g. like this:

```
String a = "Default value";
if (x != null
        && x.getY() != null
        && x.getY().getZ() != null
        && x.getY().getZ().getValueOfA() != null) {
    a = x.getY().getZ().getValueOfA();
}
... // go on with an extracted value for a or "Default value"
```

Since I found it annoying to check all those values in between explicitely, I tried to build some lambda based function that does the check via exceptions and returns an Optional containing the needed result in case no exception was thrown and my code now looks like this:

```
public <T, R> Optional<R> tryAndReturnOptional(T x, Function<T, R> function) {
    try {
        R r = function.apply(x);
        if (r != null) {
            return Optional.of(r);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

Optional<String> v = tryAndReturnOptional(x, t -> t.getY().getZ().getValueOfA());
String a = v.orElse("Default value");
... // go on with an extracted value for a or "Default value"
```

This seems to be better but I wonder if that can be done even better or maybe by some Java predefined method that I overlooked. Since efficiency is not my main problem at this stage and most of the time the needed data exists the exceptions don't bother me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nope, still no [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) in Java, so that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an Optional of your root object and use `map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)` to get your nested value.

```
String a = Optional.of(x)
        .map(X::getY)
        .map(Y::getZ)
        .map(Z::getValueOfA)
        .orElse("Default value");
```

Comment: This looks interesting but I would prefer Optional.ofNullable just in case the original object is null already. And I personally find it less readable but I admit that it comes without the definition of new methods!